# How to Show TextView text From OneView Array to AnotherView in StoryBoard iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitextview

I am new in iOS development. I created an app that shows one array value to another view from array in Storyboard. When I do it for label then it is display well but when I do for UITextView then it is not displaying array value text in UITextView Please Give me solution.

I wrote a code for that like as

First I define two arrays like as `poemNameArray` and `poemDetailArray`. I would like to display `poemNameArray` into my UITableview cell then it was worked well.

```
self.poemNameArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20", nil];
self.poemDetailArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",@"Ten",@"Eleven",@"Twelve",@"Thirteen",@"Fourteen",@"Fifteen",@"Sixteen",@"Seventeen",@"Eighteen",@"Nineteen",@"Twenty", nil];
```

And now I would like that when UITableView cell was selected then I like to redirect in to my another view that contains one label and one UITextView I would like to print `self.poemNameArray` in to label and `poemDetailArray` into my textView for that I wrote code like as

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPoemView"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    PoemViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.poemName = [self.poemNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    destViewController.detailPoem=[self.poemDetailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
}
```

And I write my another view controller for textView and label text like as

```
self.poemLabel.text=self.poemName;
self.detailPoem.text=self.fullPoem;
```

Here `poemLabel` is my label and `detailPoem` is my textview then it is only display my label text not a textview text. Please give me solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with textView's constraints you set in storyboard.

With autolayout, labels don't need to have a width or a height because its automatically calculated from their text. I don't think UITextViews have the same behaviour.

Can you provide a screenshot showing your textView with its constraints?